# how to use Jshell meta-commands in intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jshell

When I use **/var**,the Intellij idea's jshell console show me as follows:

> ```
> ERROR: illegal start of expression   
> Rejected /var
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jshell commands are not supported yet. Please follow related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-179252